# zsh: command not found: php with xampp

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I installed xampp on Ubuntu 22.04.
Running .php files is ok.
Example directory like that.

**/opt/lampp/htdocs//helloworld.php**

That file worked and run in browser. But when I run php command on terminal, it gave me this error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Xri.png)

I thought this error happened because zsh shell.So I add .zshrc file to this.

```
export PATH=<path-to-lampp>/bin/php/<php_version>/bin:$PATH
```

Still not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. The problem is need to give symbol link i think.

My solution: run this command in terminal

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones facing the issues of PHP file not found in terminal, follow following steps:
Check if shell profile file exists:

```
~/.zshrc
```

If you get any error of file doesn’t exist, you can create one by following command:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Or:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Step 3:
To use the `XAMPP PHP` and other binaries found in `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/` by default this is the correct entry for `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` depending upon shell installed on your system:

```
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Load the changes with this (won't be needed next time you open a shell session):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your PHP path is right, you should output PHP version by `{PHP path} -v`.
2. Do you `source /.zshrc` after changing the .zshrc file?